# Best way to manage 1000+ users registering for conference events at once

Tags: web, crash, server, computer-science, ddos

We are currently in the process of organising a student conference.
The issue is that we offer several different events at the same time over the course of a week. The conference runs the whole day.

It's currently been operating on a first come, first served basis, however this has led to dramatic problems in the past, namely the server crashing almost immediately, as 1000+ students all try to get the best events as quickly as they can.

Is anyone aware of a way to best handle this so that each user has the best chance of enrolling in the events they wish to attend, firstly without the server crashing and secondly with people registering for events which have a maximum capacity, all within a few minutes? Perhaps somehow staggering the registration process or something similar?

I'm aware this is a very broad question, however I'm not sure where to look to when trying to solve this problem...

Answer (score 1):

Broad questions have equally broad answers. There are broadly two ways to handle it

1. Write more performant code so that a single server can handle the load.

   - Optimize backend code; cache data; minimize DB queries; optimize DB queries; optimize third party calls; consider storing intermediate things in memory; make judicious use of transactions trading off consistency with performance if possible; partition DB.
2. Horizontally scale - deploy multiple servers. Put a load balancer in front of your multiple front end servers. Horizontally scale DB by introducing multiple read slaves.

There are no quick fixes. It all starts with analysis first - which parts of your code are taking most time and most resources and then systematically attacking them.

Some quick fixes are possible; e.g. search results may be cached. The cache might be stale; so there would be situations where the search page shows that there are seats available, when in reality the event is full. You handle such cases on registration time. For caching web pages use a caching proxy.